# Anti-CSRF mechanism with referer header

Tags: csrf

This is not my main anti-CSRF mechanism; I know that https requests don't have a referer header; I know users or firewalls can remove it or set to an arbitrary fixed value.

I intend this mechanism just as a possible added security layer preventing CSRF in case my main mechanism is bypassed for some reason.

My code will be something like this:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
if(parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST)!=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
exit('Anti-CSRF mechanism!');
```

I think this has no support and usability problems. right?

Comment: See [Does the practice of blocking an off-site “Referer:” HTTP requests improve website security?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/7944/396)

Answer (score 7):

Although checking the [HTTP referer header is a method of mitigating CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet),
this proposed PHP implementation is bypassed by omitting the referer,  which can be done using a [meta referer policy](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Meta_referrer).  If the CSRF exploit originates from an HTTPS site then the referer will be absent, and this absent case is not checked for in the above code.   The lack of a referer should be considered an attack.   However, a much better anti-csrf method is using a synchronization token.

Comment: How is it trivial to bypass?  Yes the referer can be spoofed but not during a CSRF attack.  Direct quote from OWASP : `Although it is trivial to spoof the referer header on your own browser, it is impossible to do so in a CSRF attack`

Comment: @pllee the PHP snip does not call `exit()` if the `http_referer` is absent.  Although the referer cannot be changed,  it is trivial to omit using a meta referer policy.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification is there any potential security holes in checking the referer/origin and blocking if it is null ?  Assuming the user's browser has no header changing plugins and they are not on an 2007 version of FF which has a referer bug in it.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to lose CSRF mitigations using `Referer` at HTTP. Practical demonstration could be accessed here: http://attacker.kotowicz.net/lose-referer/test.php#

Quoting bypasses from above link:

> Bypasses: GET requests
>
> ```
> data: with location= - Chrome / Safari
> window.open() - MSIE
> data: with meta refresh - Firefox / Opera / Chrome / Safari
> ```
>
> POST requests
>
> ```
> data: with meta refresh & form submit - Firefox / Chrome / Safari
> ```

A better option could be `Origin` or `NoRefferer`.